# Django Template CharField value check

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm working on a Django Website and I'm trying to implement a very basic condition in my template, a null or empty field check in a ModelForm field. I'm not sure to be able to do conditional display with divs but my first condition is always true. I only initialized the form and passed it to the template, so I don't undestand how my CharField can have a value, and I have the same problem for a FileField just below.

**models.py**

```
class Alias(models.Model):
    lexeme = models.ForeignKey(Lexeme, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    alias_value = models.CharField(_("Value"), max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(_("Language"), choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICE, max_length=40, default='en')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Alias"
        verbose_name_plural = "Aliases"
        ordering = ["alias_value"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.alias_value
```

**forms.py**

```
class AliasForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alias
        fields = ['alias_value', 'language']
```

**views.py**

```
alias_form = AliasForm(initial={'alias_value': alias.alias_value,
                                'language': alias.language})
```

But here, alias.alias_value equals None.

**template.html**

```
{% if alias_form.alias_value %}
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        {% else %}
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template `alias_form.alias_value` will give you field itself. To check field value you can use:

```
{% if alias_form.alias_value.value %}
```

Comment: That's basically what I was looking for. Thanks !